# How do I return formatted string from a function?

Tags: .net, f#

I am learning F# so pardon me if this is very basic. I have a function that is supposed to return formatted string:

```
> let getDoubled x =  sprintf "%d doubled is %d" x, x * 2;;
```

But when I execute this function it returns the following:

```
> getDoubled 2;;
val it : (int -> string) * int = (<fun:getDoubled@24-1>, 4)
```

I know I can use .NET's `string.Format` but was wondering if there was any F# way of doing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your sprintf call, try this:

```
let getDoubled x =  sprintf "%d doubled is %d" x (x * 2)
```

The comma means you are constructing a tuple, and this is what you have in your second snippet - a tuple of a  function (your partially applied `sprintf` that's waiting for the second argument) and an int (the result of `x*2`).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need the commas.

This:

```
let getDoubled x =  sprintf "%d doubled is %d" x, x * 2
```

Should be:

```
let getDoubled x =  sprintf "%d doubled is %d" x (x * 2)
```